# npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue

Tags: cordova, npm

I'm getting below warning while installing cordova. How I can resolve it?

[image]
Please see the image to know what happened when i ran below commands :

**npm update minimatch@3.0.2**

**npm update -d**

[image]

Comment: is there anyone who can help me out.

Comment: minimix: command not found

Comment: Getting this error : npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/test/npm-debug.log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115724/discussion-between-devid-farinelli-and-ngy).

Comment: Do not use sudo when running npm. If you must use `sudo` your configuration is not correct.

Comment: I didn't use sudo...

Comment: Please do not post images of text. Instead take the time to copy and paste them.

Comment: Did you mean logs of cmd?

Comment: Need expert advice... anybody there?

Answer (score 45):

`npm update -g minimatch@3.0.2`
Resolved this for me, no sweat, let me know if it doesn't work for you. Looking at your screenshots this is 90%+ likely to fix it, I think.

Looks like npm@2.15.8 which is listed in a couple of the cordova packages, has a dependency on node-gyp@3.3.1 which has a dependency on minimatch@2.0.10

This is an example of why npm is the package manager of infinite madness. I still like modern JavaScript, but npm is as dangerous as it is useful, in my opinion.

Comment: I have installed v6.2.2 Current from [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/). I tried running the update command which you have provided but it is doing nothing.

Comment: The packages I mentioned are a hard-coded dependency listed in some of the cordova packages, it isn't tied to your configuration of Node or npm, it is listed in the cordova packages so you don't have control over it. I was able to install Cordova after updating minimatch globally, but you must be having a different problem. The number of possible states that could cause this is ludicrous. Try making a new project with Cordova as the only dependency, see if it installs. "Doing nothing" must mean your global minimatch is up to date, check to confirm, please. Good luck!

Comment: This is not working in my case:$ npm update -g minimatch@3.0.2
$ sudo npm install -g cordova
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
/usr/local/bin/cordova -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
/usr/local/lib
└── cordova@6.2.0

Comment: npm really is a beast. I'm currently trying to resist feelings of actual hatred for it, it is causing an infinite loop of problems with cordova.

Comment: @Deborah Eek! I try not to think about that. It is one of the few subjects where I'm keeping my head willfully in the sand, and my butt firmly on the fence.

Comment: :D !!  I'll be there with you in six hours or so when problems are solved and calm restored!

Comment: I don't use PowerShell, the recent Edit is ludicrous, why was it approved? No idea.

Answer (score 30):

## This is what I did to update minimatch

Following a [comment on this GitHub issue](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/2952),

```
$ npm update minimatch
$ npm -v
2.10.1
$ npm install -g npm@3
/usr/local/bin/npm -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
npm@3.10.5 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
$ npm install -g minimatch@3.0.2
/usr/local/lib
└─┬ minimatch@3.0.2 
  └─┬ brace-expansion@1.1.6 
    ├── balanced-match@0.4.2 
    └── concat-map@0.0.1 

$ npm -v
3.10.5
$npm view minimatch version
3.0.2
```

Comment: Jeremy's answer didn't work for me, but this did. Seems I needed the extra "npm install -g npm@3" line before trying to update minimatch.

Comment: 'npm -v minimatch' doesn't display the minimatch version but the version of npm you're actually using. You can try to 'npm -v dslkjfhrslkfhjezfmlhj' and you'll get the same result. An easy way to display your installed packaged and their version is this command : 'npm list -g --depth=0'.

Comment: to show the version of minimatch use: 'npm view minimatch version'

Comment: @n3wbie and Asimov - thanks, commands updated accordingly :-)

Answer (score 6):

I got this message when I was trying to install **ember-cli** and solved by typing following command:

`npm install -g npm`

The command basically will update your `npm` and hope it will solve your problem too. :)

UPDATED:

But:

**Note** that as it stands if anyone runs *npm* install from a cloned version of your repository they will end up with the old, vulnerable version of minimatch and will see the error message warning them of a vulnerability.

So you need to run the above command again.

Comment: Actually other answers didn't resolve.. but this one did!

Answer (score 1):

Just type in "npm install -g minimatch@3.0.2" (Without the quotes). That will do
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did:

```
$ npm install -g minimatch
```

After this everything installed with no error messages.

Comment: This is the easiest, most accurate solution.

Answer (score -1):

run command as follows:

1. ->npm update
2. ->npm install -g cordova

this worked for me.