# npm install -g minimatch@3.0.2

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I have Updated by writing command "npm install -g minimatch@3.0.2".
but still show----
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue

Comment: How i fix it. Any expert there???

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38046392/npm-warn-deprecated-minimatch2-0-10-please-update-to-minimatch-3-0-2-or-higher/38077214
`npm install -g npm@3`

`npm install -g minimatch@3.0.2`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38046392/npm-warn-deprecated-minimatch2-0-10-please-update-to-minimatch-3-0-2-or-higher)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you have another package that is including minmatch@2.0.10 as a dependency. If you run `npm ls minmatch` then it will show you which packages call this.