# npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10 but I have a newer version

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, minimatch

> npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2
>   or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue

I'm on windows 10 trying to install Cordova. I know that this question was asked a lot and if I look closely at each of the potential dupes I might find a dupe.

But before you close my question as a dupe, I just want you to know that I took a look at some of them, and that I did `npm update -g minimatch`

```
C:\Users\user\npm ls minimatch
C:\Users\user
`-- cordova@6.3.1
  +-- cordova-common@1.4.1
  | `-- minimatch@3.0.3
  `-- cordova-lib@6.3.1
    +-- cordova-js@4.1.4
    | `-- browserify@10.1.3
    |   `-- glob@4.5.3
    |     `-- minimatch@2.0.10
    `-- npm@2.15.11
      `-- minimatch@3.0.3
```

As you can see, a library in cordova is still holding on to the old minimatch, how to get rid of it?

Comment: Did you also update `npm` as suggested [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38077214/893780)?

Comment: @robertklep you mean jeremy's answer? to a specific version? no I didn't, I just let it update to the latest version

Comment: @robertklep please check my update

Comment: What version of node.js?

Comment: @JulianKnight i tried 4.5, 4 and now 4.7, I opened a bug at apache jira cordova project and it's critical, and they said that browserify hasn't updated to glob 7 https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/pull/1602 I'll answer my own question when the bug is closed, unless some nice guy here manages to solve it before browserify does

Comment: With v4.x you should not update npm to latest but rather do `npm update npm@2 -g`. If you switch from 4 to something later, you will be using npm v3 which uses a different, flatter structure and you should delete the node_modules folder and reinstall.

Comment: @JulianKnight I deleted the node modules and reinstalled and ran `npm update npm@2 -g` and i checked the version now and I have npm version   3.10.8 which is the same version I believe I was using yesterday because I believe it didn't downgrage. Anyhow thanks for the info, I'll always keep that in mind

Comment: Something is wrong. If you globally installed npm@2 and still getting v3. So it looks like you have deeper problems.

Comment: @JulianKnight I think it's time to ask you how to debug and detect the problem but I guess your answer would be `son, it's JS, do you truly think you could debug JS, you foolish kid!`

Comment: @Lynob: Ha ha! It's not really that hard! But the problem here is probably Linux installs more than node/npm.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that a dependency uses an old version of minimatch. You can find it by using

```
npm ls minimatch
```

See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls

Comment: it shows the following output http://pastebin.com/ahSh2jgt cant seem to update glob nor browserify nor cordova

Comment: @Lynob `npm -v` returns the version of npm itself. You can even type `npm -v foobarbaz` and it still does.

Answer (score 0):

You have other packages that you're bringing in that have older versions of minimatch.

Comment: I know, as discussed with cordova team, browesrify which a dependency of cordova needs to upgrade to glob 7 in order to use the newer version of minimatch, the fix was released in early august but not yet merged into the master repo