# npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue

Tags: npm, gulp

npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue

[image]

Comment: use `npm install gulp -g` https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally

Comment: also, this question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38046392/npm-warn-deprecated-minimatch2-0-10-please-update-to-minimatch-3-0-2-or-higher?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38046392/npm-warn-deprecated-minimatch2-0-10-please-update-to-minimatch-3-0-2-or-higher)